# In Flash or Air for iOS, will using both stage and stage3d enable you to use excess CPU/GPU resource on the device?

Tags: ios, flash, air, rendering, gpu

As stage3d uses GPU to draw and stage DisplayObjects mostly uses CPU to draw, I was wondering if using both stage and stage3d enables you to use the CPU/GPU resource that each instance doesn't use much?

My game uses some heavy vector graphics( which have too long animations that they can't be cashed as stage3d textures) and it would be great if stage can render them using CPU and leave everything else to stage3d(GPU).

Would it work like that?